# Checking the data latency on an Always On Availability Group in ASYNC mode

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

We have a number of SQL Servers with Always on Availability Groups in asynchronous mode between a primary and secondary server with Manual fail over.

I created a latency report utilizing the below query that collects the data every min on each server.

On one of our servers the secondary routinely shows that it has an earlier last_commit_time then the primary.

I verified the server times are the same on both servers.

Why might this be?

[image: Graph showing AVG Daily Latency per database]

```
;WITH 
        AG_Stats AS 
                (
                SELECT  AR.replica_server_name,
                        AG.name as AGName,
                        HARS.role_desc, 
                        Db_name(DRS.database_id) [DBName], 
                        DRS.last_commit_time
                FROM   sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states DRS 
                INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AR ON DRS.replica_id = AR.replica_id 
                INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states HARS ON AR.group_id = HARS.group_id 
                    AND AR.replica_id = HARS.replica_id 
                INNER JOIN [sys].[availability_groups] AG on AG.group_id = AR.group_id
                ),
        Pri_CommitTime AS 
                (
                SELECT  replica_server_name
                        , AGNAME
                        , DBName
                        , last_commit_time
                FROM    AG_Stats
                WHERE   role_desc = 'PRIMARY'
                ),
        Sec_CommitTime AS 
                (
                SELECT  replica_server_name
                        , AGNAME
                        , DBName
                        , last_commit_time
                FROM    AG_Stats
                WHERE   role_desc = 'SECONDARY'
                )
    SELECT p.replica_server_name [primary_replica]
        , p.AGNAME
        , p.[DBName] AS [DatabaseName]
        , s.replica_server_name [secondary_replica]
        , DATEDIFF(ss,s.last_commit_time,p.last_commit_time) AS [Sync_Latency_Secs]
    FROM Pri_CommitTime p
    LEFT JOIN Sec_CommitTime s ON [s].[DBName] = [p].[DBName] and  s.AGNAME = p.AGNAME
```

Comment: Just for clarification, when you state `the secondary routinely shows that it has an earlier last_commit_time then the primary`, you mean if the time is say 1pm, the primary shows 1pm and the secondary shows 12:55pm, correct?

Comment: role_desc  last_commit_time
PRIMARY  2019-12-10 10:23:17.370
SECONDARY  2019-12-10 10:23:12.367

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is worth noting that the value for [`last_commit_time`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is defined differently based on whether it is being queried from the secondary or primary replica.

> On the secondary database, this time is the same as on the primary
>   database.
>
> On the primary replica, each secondary database row displays the time
>   that the secondary replica that hosts that secondary database has
>   reported back to the primary replica. The difference in time between
>   the primary-database row and a given secondary-database row represents
>   approximately the recovery point objective (RPO), assuming that the
>   redo process is caught up and that the progress has been reported back
>   to the primary replica by the secondary replica.

In addition to the above, a secondary replica that has a delay of a few seconds on the commit will yield a positive number, but one that hasn't finished the commit yet will yield a negative number in your query.

So if you have a latency of 10 seconds but query at the 5 second mark, since there is no commit time yet on the secondary for the primary's last commit, you're going to get the *previous* commit time which is probably before the primary's latest commit time. This is expected with asynchronous replication.

Comment: OK, so I need to include last_commit_lsn to make sure I'm comparing the same transaction.

Comment: In this case wouldn't the current lag time be from the primary's last_commit_time and the time of the query's execution?

Comment: Yup, I misspoke above - will delete that comment.

Answer (score 0):

Modified the query I'm using based on LowlyDBA's answer.

```
    ;WITH 
        AG_Stats AS 
                (
                SELECT  AR.replica_server_name,
                        AG.name as AGName,
                        HARS.role_desc, 
                        Db_name(DRS.database_id) [DBName], 
                        DRS.last_commit_time
                FROM   sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states DRS 
                INNER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AR ON DRS.replica_id = AR.replica_id 
                INNER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states HARS ON AR.group_id = HARS.group_id 
                    AND AR.replica_id = HARS.replica_id 
                INNER JOIN [sys].[availability_groups] AG on AG.group_id = AR.group_id

                ),
        Pri_CommitTime AS 
                (
                SELECT  replica_server_name
                        , AGNAME
                        , DBName
                        , last_commit_time
                FROM    AG_Stats
                WHERE   role_desc = 'PRIMARY'
                ),
        Sec_CommitTime AS 
                (
                SELECT  replica_server_name
                        , AGNAME
                        , DBName
                        , last_commit_time
                FROM    AG_Stats
                WHERE   role_desc = 'SECONDARY'
                )
    SELECT p.replica_server_name [primary_replica]
        , p.AGNAME
        , p.[DBName] AS [DatabaseName]
        , s.replica_server_name [secondary_replica]
        , CASE 
                WHEN s.last_commit_time >= p.last_commit_time THEN DATEDIFF(ss,s.last_commit_time,p.last_commit_time) 
                ELSE DATEDIFF(ss,p.last_commit_time,GETDATE()) 
          END AS [Sync_Latency_Secs]
    FROM Pri_CommitTime p
    LEFT JOIN Sec_CommitTime s ON [s].[DBName] = [p].[DBName] and  s.AGNAME = p.AGNAME
```